# The meaning of tense in Wh- clause

Tags: meaning

> The Management Board of the Agencyshall, on the basis of an
>   independent audit report that takes into account the recommendations
>   of the Pharmacovigilance Risk Assessment Committee, **confirm and
>   announce when the repository *has achieved* full functionality and
>   *meets* the functional specifications drawn up pursuant to the second paragraph.** [EU Regulations](https://ec.europa.eu/health/sites/health/files/files/eudralex/vol-1/reg_2004_726/reg_2004_726_en.pdf)

I'd like to ask about the reason why the writer uses "has achieved" (the present perfect) and "meets" (the simple present) in one When clause.

And could you let me know the meaning of this When clause?
I think it could be interpeted in two ways as follows:

1) The board has to confirm and announce what day/what time the repository has to achieve full functionality and has to meet the specifications. (= the Board has to confirm and announce the deadline for the repository to be ready.)

2) The board has to confirm and announce what day/what time the repository *achieved* full functionality and *met* the specifications.

Please help me.

Comment: Please keep your questions as short as possible. We volunteers only have a certain amount of time available.

Comment: @BillJ Could you please let me know how to make this question shorter than this?

Comment: The first paragraph is not necessary.

Comment: @BillJ  Thank you. I removed it.

Comment: Nor is the first sentence of the quote necessary

Comment: @marcellothearcane Thanks. I also deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

> ...when the repository has achieved full functionality and meets the functional specifications drawn up pursuant to the second paragraph.

This is idiomatic to my ear.

'When' means that after a condition is fulfilled, a state is reached.

> after which; and just then (implying suddenness). ([Source](https://lexico.com/en/definition/when))

In this sentence, they are saying that the condition of 'full functionality' needs to be reached before the specifications are met. 
 You don't keep on achieving something once it has been achieved - it is a completed action, so using past tense is right.

The present tense is used because the state of full functionality *will continue to be relevant*.

Comment: @MangoGummy has this answer helped you? Is there anything that I need to explain?